# How to copy file from res:// location to user:// location in godot

Tags: android, godot

I am trying to move a file from res:// to user:// location. Below is my code

```
#copydb
var dir = Directory.new();
dir.copy("res://gk.db","user://gk.db");
```

But I am getting the following error

> Parse Error: Unexpected token: Identifier:dir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code inside a function and indented it. There was no error. You may be writing that code outside of a function. I got your error when I did that.